# What is this panel indicator in the status menu and what is the problem?

Tags: icons, indicator, menu, panel

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed. There is one application that does not seem to work well at my laptop. Does anyone know which application has this icon and what is the problem here? When I right-click it an empty menu opens.

[image: Which application is this]
[image: A transparent empty menu with no entries]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon indicates "something is missing".

The last time I had it there were problems with a HP printer program.

Take a look into *startup applications* to see which applet/indicator is missing.